# How to prevent a refreshing Dataflow to get into a deadlock

Tags: powerbi

Occasionally the following error (with the message below retrieved from the Web UI) prevents a PowerBI Dataflow to refresh successfully. The Dataflow is running in a Workspace backed by Premium Capacity and it is built from a linked entity.

> Error: Data Source Error : DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL:
> Transaction (Process ID 83) was deadlocked on lock resources with
> another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
> transaction. DataSourceKind = SQL DataSourcePath = .\cdsasqlcache

Are there any recommendations on how to prevent this from happening or any guidelines on how to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Are you using RCSI isolation?

Comment: @Stu do you know how transaction isolation levels appy to Dataflows? in other words how/where to set them up?